# How to convert UTF-8 text from file to some container which can be iterable and check every symbol for being alphanumeric in C++?

Tags: c++, utf-8, isalpha

I read around 20 questions and checked documentation about it with no success, I don't have any experience writing code handling this stuff, I always avoided it.

Let's say I have a file which I am sure always will be UTF-8:

> á

Let's say I have code:

```
  wifstream input{argv[1]};
  wstring line;
  getline(input, line);
```

When I debug it, I see it's stored as `L"Ã¡"`, so basically it's not iterable as I want, I want to have just 1 symbol to be able to call let's say `iswalnum(line[0])`.

I realized that there is some codecvt facet, but I am not sure, how to use it and if it's the best way and I use cl.exe from VS2019 which gives me a lot of conversion and deprecation errors on the example provided:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8

I realized that there is a from_bytes function, but I use cl.exe from VS2019 which gives me a lot of errors on the example provided, too:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/from_bytes

So how to correctly read the line with let's say that letter (symbol) `á` and be able to iterate it as some container with size 1 so some function like `iswalnum` can be simply called?

EDIT: When I fix the bugs in those examples (for c++latest), I still have `Ä‚Ë‡` in UTF-8 and `Ăˇ` in UTF-16.

Comment: @rustyx Nice help, I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L"Ã¡"` means the file was read with a wrong encoding. You have to [imbue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) a UTF-8 locale before reading the stream.

```
  wifstream input{argv[1]};
  input.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));
  wstring line;
  getline(input, line);
```

Now `wstring line` will contain Unicode code points (`á` in your case) and can be easily iterated.

---

Caveat: on Windows `wchar_t` is deficient (16-bit), and is good enough for iterating over [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) only.

Comment: Thanks, I already realized that I had the same problem in the past, because I remember searching for a suitable fstream constructor with locale, there isn't any.